# Sorting a permutation with minimum cost

Tags: algorithm

I am given a permutation of elements `{1, 2, 3, ..., N}` and I have to sort it using a swap operation. An operation which swaps elements x, y has cost min(x,y).

I need to find out the minimum cost of sorting the permutation. I tought about a greedy going from `N` to `1` and putting  each element on it's position using a swap operation, but this is not a good idea.

Comment: So, do I get the question right: You are give a permutation. For this given permutation, you need to find the minimum cost of sorting it using that swap operation with that cost per swap?

Comment: The swap cost, are X and Y elements final position or value, or are they the position element is currently at?

Comment: ...actually, is this a trick question? If cost is min(x,y), then you always swap with 1... Two swaps to get element to right position.

Comment: @hyde - No, consider `[4,3,2,1]` - optimal is swapping (1,4) and (2,3) at cost 3.

Comment: @dfb Ah yeah, there are a few special cases... Also the case of element already being at right spot. Also mostly just 1 swap per element, not two (swap 1 with the element that should go to position where 1 is now).

Comment: Are seeks considered trivial and the only cost is the value of the swap, or is examined as a traditional sorting algorithm where the only operation is a swap?

Answer (score 2):

Would this be optimal:

```
Find element 2
If it is not at correct place already

    Find element at position 2
    If swapping that with 2 puts both to right place

        Swap them
        Cost = Cost + min(2, other swapped element)

repeat

   Find element 1
   If element 1 is at position 1

      Find first element that is in wrong place
      If no element found

          set sorted true

      else

         Swap found element with element 1
         Cost = Cost + 1

   else

      Find element that should go to the position where 1 is
      Swap found element with element 1
      Cost = Cost + 1

until sorted is true
```

Comment: My own reservations about this algorithm are: 1. is it ok to first deal with 2, or would it be better to deal with it somewhere in the middle of the loop, with some condition? 2. Does it matter which element at wrong is selected for swappping with 1, when 1 ends up at it's own place?

Comment: @WLPhoenix fine fine, replaced gotos, didn't even use break. happy? ;)

Answer (score 2):

If seeks are trivial, then the minimum number of swaps will be determined by the number of cycles. It would follow a principle similar to [Cuckoo Hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing). You take the first value in the permutation, and look at the value at the index of the value at the original index. If those match, then swap for a single operation.

[**3** 2 1] : Value 3 is at index one, so look at the value at index 3. 
[3 2 **1**] : Value 1 is at index 3, so a two index cycle exists. Swap these values.

If not, push the first index onto a stack and seek the index for the value of the second index. There will eventually be a cycle. At that point, start swapping by popping values off the stack. This will take a number of swaps equal to n-1, where n is the length of the cycle.

[**3** 1 2] : Value 3 is at index one, so look at the value at index 3. 
[3 1 **2**] : Value 2 is at index 3, so add 3 to the stack and seek to index 2. Also store 3 as the beginning value of the cycle.
[3 **1** 2] : Value 1 is at index 2, so add 2 to the stack and seek to index 1. 
[**3** 1 2] : Value 3 is the beginning of the cycle, so swap pop 2 off the stack and swap values 1 and 2. 
[1 3 2] : Pop 3 off the stack and swap 2 and 3, resulting in a sorted list with 2 swaps.

[1 2 3]

With this algorithm, the maximum number of swaps will be N-1, where N is the total number of values. This occurs when there is an N length cycle.

**EDIT :** This algorithm gives the minimum number of swaps, but not necessarily the minimum value using the min(x, y) function. I haven't done the math, but I believe that the only time when swap(x, y) = {swap(1, x), swap(1, y), swap(1, x)} shouldn't be used is when x in {2,3} and n < 2; Should be easy enough to write that as a special case. It may be better to check and place 2 and 3 explicitly, then follow the algorithm mentioned in the comments to achieve sorting in two operations.

**EDIT 2 :** Pretty sure this will catch all cases.

```
while ( unsorted ) {
    while ( 1 != index(1) )
        swap (1 , index (1) )

    if (index(2) == value@(2))
        swap (2, value@(2) )

    else
        swap (1 , highest value out of place)
}
```

Comment: It's not letting me edit for some reason, but that if should also have the condition that 2 and value@(2) are the only values out of place.

Answer (score 0):

If you have **permutation** of the numbers 1, 2, ..., *N*, then the *sorted* collection will be precisely 1, 2, ..., *N*. So you know the answer with complexity O(0) (i.e. you don't need an algorithm at all).

---

If you actually want to sort the range by repeated swapping, you can repeatedly "advance and cycle": Advance over the already sorted range (where `a[i] == i`), and then swap `a[i]` with `a[a[i]]` until you complete the cycle. Repeat until you reach the end. That needs at most *N* − 1 swaps, and it basically performs a cycle decomposition of the permutation.

Comment: The OP needs to find the cost

Comment: I think the question is to compute the minimal number of swaps to get from the permutation to {1, 2, ..., N}.

Comment: @dfb The cost is zero. However, I believe that OP didn't express themselves correctly.

Comment: The minimal number of swaps is N-1, obviously, but the cost of each swap varies. The actual cost will likely vary.

Comment: Huh? OP is specifying a cost function ( An operation which swaps elements x, y has cost min(x,y) )

Comment: @Vesper not true, what if some of the elements are in the right place already?

Comment: @japreiss Indeed, so the actual minimum is still 0, if the permutation is already sorted. This needs some explanation from the OP, the question sounds as requesting the algorithm that has the lowest **maximum** cost for **any** permutation. So maybe we are just baffled here.

Comment: It sounds to me like the algorithm should take a permutation as input and return the shortest possible sequence of swaps that rearranges the input into sorted order.

Comment: Looks like my algorithm qualifies for this task... It's more detailed in hyde's answer up there.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. An interesting question. A quick algorithm that came up to my mind is to use elements as indices. We first find the index of an element that has 1 as value, and swap it with element of that number. Eventually this will end up with 1 appearing at first position, this means you have to swap 1 with some element that isn't yet in the position, and continue. This tops at 2*N-2, and has lower limit at N-1 for permutation (2,3,...,N,1), but the exact cost will vary.

Okay, given above algorithm and examples, I think the most optimal will be to follow exchanging 1 with anything until it first hits first place, then exchange 2 with second-place if it's not in place already, then continue swapping 1 with anything not yet in place, until sorted.

```
set sorted=false
while (!sorted) {
    if (element 1 is in place) {
        if (element 2 is in place) {
            find any element NOT in place
            if (no element found) sorted=true 
            else {
                swap 1 with element found
                cost++
            }
        } else {
            swap 2 with element at second place
            cost+=2
        }
    } else {
        find element with number equals to position of element 1
        swap 1 with element found
        cost++
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at the example [4,3,2,1] in the actual questions comments, with optimal cost of 3, unattainable by swapping only with 1, correct algorithm needs to be more complex.

Comment: Okay, a counterexample [2,3,1] with your algorithm you end up with 3, with mine, 2 - exchange 1 with 3, then 1 with 2.

Comment: true, I suspect the whole algorirhm needs to be quite a bit more complex, though I think I'll change my version a bit to make it cover both [4,3,2,1] and [2,3,1] anyway.

Comment: The issue is still based on number cycles. If 2 is in a 2 index cycle, then a single swap will always be the most efficient. Otherwise, it's best to just swap 1 into the cycle and let it filter all the way through the cycle, then repeat.

Answer (score -1):

Use a bucket sort with bucket size of 1.
The cost is zero, since no swaps occur.
Now make a pass through the bucket array, and swap each value back to it's corresponding position in the original array.
That is N swaps.
The sum of N is N(N+1)/2 giving you an exact fixed cost.

A different interpretation is that you just store from the bucket array, back into the original array.  That is no swaps, hence the cost is zero, which is a reasonable minimum.